# Dynamic Programing- complexity

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, dynamic-programming

I have a homework problem that I have been trying to figure out for some time now, and I can't figure it out for the life of me.

I have a sheet of size X*Y, and a set of patterns of lesser sizes, with price values associated with them. I can cut the sheet either horizontally or vertically, and I have to find the optimized cutting pattern to get the greatest profit from the sheet.

As far as I can tell there should be (X*Y)(X+Y+#ofPatterns) recursive operations. The complexity is supposed to be exponential. Can someone please explain why?

The pseudo-code I have come up with is as follows:

```
Optimize( w, h ) {
best_price = 0
    for(Pattern p :  all patterns) {
        if ( p fits into this piece of cloth && p’s price > best price) {best_price = p’s price}
    }
    for (i = 1…n){
       L= Optimize( i, h );
       R= Optimize( w-i, h);
       if (L_price + R_price > best_price) { update best_price}
    }
    for (i = 1…n){
        T= Optimize( w, i );
        B= Optimize( w, h-i);
        if (T_price + B_price > best_price) { update best_price}
    }
return best_price;
}
```

Comment: I suppose it depends on which loop. for the loop of horizontal cuts n=h-1 and for vertical cuts it is w-1. Or was that a question that was supposed to push me in the right direction? :)

Comment: No, it wasn't a hint!  I started to write an answer, and then realised I couldn't because I didn't know how many times the loops were iterating.

Comment: I have implemented it with a memory table as well. With dynamic programming the solution should be polynomial. Since the table is of size WxH only W*H solutions are needed.

Comment: After read again, I understand now....Based on your code, it maybe n^2logn. You can try to rewrite it with memory tables,it is easier to get complexity

Comment: @ReezaCoriza If you have rewritten in memory tables, how deep your have looped;e.g. for{for}} is n^2。In most of the time, it can be considered as nlogn, and in worst scenario is n^2. At last, the final answer is based on which kind of complexity function you are using(e.g. O, o).

Comment: I am using big O. Worst case with memory table is n^2. I am most confused by the non-DP solution.

If n recursive calls are needed to derive the first optimal cut, are n-1 needed to find the second, and n-2 the third... etc etc?

Answer (score 0):

The recursive case is exponential because you can at the start choose to cut your paper 0 to max width inches or 0 to max height inches and then optionally cut the remaining pieces (recurse).

This problem sounds like a bit more interesting case of this rod cutting problem since it involves two dimensions.

http://www.radford.edu/~nokie/classes/360/dp-rod-cutting.html

is a good guide. Read that should put you on the right track without blatantly answering your homework.

The relevant portion to why it is exponential when recursing:

```
This recursive algorithm uses the formula above and is slow
Code
    -- price array p, length n
    Cut-Rod(p, n)
        if n = 0 then
            return 0
        end if
        q := MinInt
        for i in 1 .. n loop
            q = max(q, p(i) + Cut-Rod(p, n-i)
        end loop
        return q

Recursion tree (shows subproblems): 4/[3,2,1,0]//[2,1,0],[1,0],0//[1,0],0,0//0
Performance: Let T(n) = number of calls to Cut-Rod(x, n), for any x
T(0)=0
T(n)=1+∑i=1nT(n−i)=1+∑j=0n−1T(j)
Solution: T(n)=2n
```

Comment: I understand it in relation to the rod cutting problem. Essentially, if I find an optimal cut for an n-length rod, at position i, I still have to find the optimal cuts for the rest of the rod, n-i. I guess I am having trouble wrapping my head around it in 2-dimentions.

Comment: In any case, thanks for your help. I am terrible with analyzing complexity. I just need to keep doing it until I get it.

Answer (score 0):

When calculating the complexity of a dynamic programming algorithm, we can decompose it into two subproblems: one is calculating the **number of substates**; and the other is calculating the **time complexity of solving a particular subproblem**.

But it's true that when you don't use a memoization approach, the algorithm that has a polynomial time complexity in nature would increase to exponential time complexity since you are not re-using information that you've previously calculated. (I'm pretty sure you understand this part from your dynamic programming course)

No matter whether you solve a dynamic programming problem using the memoization method or the bottom-up approach, the time complexity stays the same. I think the trouble you are having is that you are trying to draw the function call graph in your head. Instead, let's try to estimate the number of function calls this way.

You are saying that there are (X*Y)(X+Y+#ofPatterns) recursive calls.

**Well, yes and no.**

It's true that when you use a memoization method, there are only this many number of recursive calls. Because if you have called and calculated a certain Optimize(w0,h0), the value will be stored and the next time another function Optimize(w1,h1) calls Optimize(w0,h0), it won't do these redundant work again. And that's what makes the time complexity polynomial.

But in your current implementation, one subproblem Optimize(w0,h0) gets many redundant function calls, which means the number of recursive calls in your algorithm is not polynomial at all (for a simple example, try to draw the call graph of the recursive Fibonacci number algorithm).